# Взаимодействие Java c MQ очередями

Tags: java, jms, ibm, activemq

Всем привет! Есть интересный вопрос, возможно ли как то привинтить слушателя MQ очередей с помощью java? Нашел код который позволяет записывать сообщение в MQ очередь и вычитывать из MQ очереди, но для каждой вычитки сообщений необходимо явно вызывать метод, хотелось бы каким то образом настроить слушателя MQ очереди и если в очередь кладут сообщение, то сразу его вычитывать и удалять из очереди.
Кусок кода с помощью которого записываю(**JmsProducer.java**) и вычитываю(**JmsBrowser.java**) сообщения из очереди.

**JmsProducer.java**

```
package mq;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

@Slf4j
public class JmsProducer extends JmsBase {
    private MessageProducer producer = null;

    public JmsProducer() {
        super();
        try {
            if (producer != null)
                producer.close();
        } catch (JMSException jmse) {
            recordFailure(jmse);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAction(String msg) {
        if (msg == null) {
            log.error("Error, it is impossible to put a null message");
        } else {
            try {
                producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
                producer.send(message);
                log.info("JMS сообщение отправлено!\n");

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                status = -2;
                log.info("JMS сообщение не отправлено!\n" + e);
                recordFailure(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (producer != null) producer.close();
                } catch (JMSException jmse) {
                    recordFailure(jmse);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeMessage(String msg){
        init();
        doAction(msg);
        destroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAction() {

    }
}
```

**JmsBrowser.java**

```
package mq;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.QueueBrowser;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class JmsBrowser  extends  JmsBase{

    private QueueBrowser queueBrowser = null;

    public JmsBrowser(){
        super();
        try {
            if (queueBrowser != null)
                queueBrowser.close();
        } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
            recordFailure(jmsex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAction() {
        try {
            queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(destination);
            // Чтение сообщений
            Enumeration<?> messages = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();

            int count = 0;
            Message message;
            // Просмотр сообщений
            System.out.println("Просмотр JMS сообщений : ");
            while (messages.hasMoreElements()) {
                message = (Message) messages.nextElement();
                System.out.println("\nСообщение " + (++count) + " :");
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void readMessage(){
        destroy();
        init();
        doAction();
        destroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAction(String msg) {

    }
}
```

**JmsBase.java**

```
package mq;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;

@Slf4j
public abstract class JmsBase {
    // статус выполнения приложения
    protected static int status = 1;
    protected Session session = null;
    protected Queue destination = null;
    protected Connection connection = null;
    private String host = "localhost";
    private int port = 1417;
    private String channel = "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN";
    private String queueManagerName = "IBM2QMGR";
    private String queueName = "REQUEST";
    private boolean clientTransport = false;

    protected abstract void doAction();

    protected abstract void doAction(String msg);

    protected void init(){
        try {
            createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            destination = session.createQueue(queueName);
            connection.start();
        }
        catch (JMSException jmsex) {
            recordFailure(jmsex);
        }
    }

    protected void destroy(){
        try {
            if (session != null)
                session.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
            log.error("" + jmsex.getMessage());
            recordFailure(jmsex);
        }
    }
    private void createConnection() {
        JmsFactoryFactory ff;
        JmsConnectionFactory cf;
        try {
            ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(
                    WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

            // Set the properties
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, host);
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
            if (clientTransport) {
                cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE,
                        WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            } else {
                cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE,
                        WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
            }
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER,
                    queueManagerName);
            connection = cf.createConnection();
        } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
            recordFailure(jmsex);
        }
    }

}
```

Подскажите, с помощью чего можно реализовать данную задачу, если это вообще возможно реализовать с помощью Java. Буду признателен за подсказку

Comment: Что вы понимаете по словом слушатель?

Comment: Объект уведомляющий о некотором событии, в данном случае уведомляющий о новом сообщении в очереди

Comment: И как он уведомляет? В какой очереди?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jms+queue+listener+java+example

Ищите в примерах setMessageListener